# DiscriminatorColumn is not created in deep entity inheritance in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I want to create a deep inheritance entity using jpa. Below is the sample hierarcy of my entities.

```
ProductEntity
- ElectronicsEntity
-- PhoneEntity
-- TabletEntity
-- CameraEntity
-- ComputerEntity
--- PCEntity
--- LaptopEntity
- AccessoriesEntity
-- CasingEntity
-- ScreenProtectorEntity
```

Below is the sample of several class of my entities.

**ProductEntity**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    String brand;
    private String name;
    private String image;
}
```

**ElectronicsEntity**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Electronics")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class Electronics extends Product {
    private Date releasedDate;
}
```

**PhoneEntity**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Phone")
public class Phone extends Electronics {
    private String os;
    private String cpu;
    private String gpu;
    private int ram;
    private double display;
    private double rearCamera;  
    private double frontCamera;
    private int battery;
    private double weight;
}
```

**TabletEntity**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Tablet")
public class Tablet extends Electronics {
    private String os;
    private String cpu;
    private String gpu;
    private int ram;
    private double display;
    private double rearCamera;  
    private double frontCamera;
    private int battery;
    private double weight;
}
```

The problem is my database is not created correctly. `Product`, `Phone`, and `Tablet` are created correctly, but `Electronics` is not. The `Electronics` table is missing the `type` column which should be there to discriminate `Phone` and `Tablet`. As you can see, I've added `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")` to the `Electronics`, so the `type` column should be added automatically, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you made any changes in entity..  like you had something before and you later added this *type* column??

Comment: previously I didn't use inheritance, but now I am trying to use it.

Comment: The problem may be Hibernate can't add a new not-null column and the Discriminator is a not-null column.. Can you just try once following code in Electronics  class where the column has def value.. __@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, columnDefinition = "varchar default 'SomeElectronic'" , length = 20)__

Comment: oh hey, now it works. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be Hibernate can't add a new not-null column and the Discriminator is a not-null column.. 
try once following code in Electronics class where the column has def value..

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, columnDefinition = "varchar default 'SomeElectronic'" , length = 20)
```